# How do I edit this text file using PHP?

Tags: php

I do have a text file having around 400k data in it. and its content is like this..

```
1,james
2,mathew
3,yancy
4,brandon
5,molner
6,nick
7,neil...and so on
```

How do I remove numbers and comas from this text file and keep only names?

Comment: I am familiar with the same thats why..even other languages also will do...I am familiar to java script,PHP,VB etc. but not that expert to write these kinda of app's

Comment: I have a tested example as answer:)

Comment: You could do this in Excel by importing the file as CSV, telling Excel that the `,` denotes a column break, which would give you numbers in the A column and names in the B column, then just delete the A column and save the file again...

Answer (score 2):

[Read](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) the file into an array, where each array item is one line. [Walk](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) throught the array, [find](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) the first comma, and [remove](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) it and everything before. Then [write](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) it all back out again.

```
// Warning! Brain-compiled code ahead.

$arr = file('myfile.txt');
foreach ( $arr as &$val )
    $val = substr($val, strpos($val, ',') + 1);
file_put_contents('myoutfile.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $arr));
```

Note - no error checking. If a line lacks a comma, or comma is the last character, chaos ensues.

Comment: This approach requires the whole file to be read into memory before anything is written. Wouldn't it be better to process the file line-by-line, so that only one line needs to be stored at any one time?

Comment: oh yeah you right I think I can do it upon to certain level will update my question

Comment: @Alex Howell - if the file was extremely huge (several MB or more) - yes. But just 400K? That will barely take any RAM at all. And the lines are short. The overhead of 10'000 read/write function calls will drown out everything else.

Comment: It's juste 400ko, so it will fits in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

400k isn't incredibly much, so you should get away with this (tested):

```
foreach (file($path) as $line)
    print preg_replace("~^[0-9]+\,(.*)~", "$1", $line);
```

Comment: PS You can save the string instead of printing it, of course.

Answer (score 0):

This is tested and will return it as a list but you can save it to a database if you want:

```
$file_path='my_file.txt';
$file_handler = fopen($file_path, 'rt');

$doc = fread($file_handler, filesize($file_path)+1);

$rows = explode("\n", $doc);
$rows_array = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $data = explode(",", $row);
        $return_array[] = $data[1];
}

//print_r($return_array);
    //you can save it to a db

echo '<ul>';
foreach($return_array as $value){
    echo '<li>'.$value.'</li>';
}   
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perl one liner that do the job:

```
perl -i.save -pe 's/^\d+,//'  test.txt
```

The original file will be saved in `test.txt.save`

Comment: # cat input.txt | sed 's/^\d,//' > test.txt # in case perl isn't there :)